# SVD Like Matrix Transformation

Tags: matrices, matlab, matrix-decomposition, svd, pseudoinverse

I am implementing a research paper in MATLAB and have encountered a matrix transformation that I don't know how to get done in MATLAB.
Here it is,

P*L*Q = [I O]
where P,Q are transformation matrices, L is the given matrix, and I,O are identity and zero matrices respectively.

Can anyone help me get this done in MATLAB through some function or an algorithm so I can implement this through my code?